# Cant ssh or ping OpenStack instances from other devices on network

Tags: ssh, ping, multiple-instances, openstack

I have done a DevStack installation of OpenStack on a server.

I have added ICMP and SSH rules to the security group. And have made instances on it.

I can ssh and ping these instances from the host machine.

Now the problem is that I'm unable to ssh or even ping my instances from other machines on this network.
And the fun part is that these instances can ssh/ping other machines and even ping my other server and ssh VM's on this server.

I hope I made sense but if you have more to ask, please let me know

Comment: I dont; know openstack per se, but it is common on multiple virtualization platforms for people to use Host-only or NAT virtual network connections on their guests, and neither of these will allow remote connection by default. since the guest can ping other network hosts, I'd guess that you are using a NAT type connection to a virtual network defined in your openstack provider/runtime, and I would recommend you change it to a "Bridged" connection, so that the guests can pull dhcp IPs from your networks DHCP servers, and generally participate as hosts on your LAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something was wrong with the gateway communication, and I was using the same interface for the provider and management network.
So when I set "proxy_arp = 1" things started to work, but there was no internet on instances.

I've started working on manual OpenStack installation and configuration for better understanding.